# Downcasting from a generic collection of superclass to a sublclass

Tags: c#, .net, oop, generics

**Consider the following scenario:**

```
public abstract class ClassA
{
    public void SomeMethod();
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public void MethodForClassB()
    {
    }
}

public class ClassC : ClassA
{
    public void MethodForClassC()
    {
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var classAList = new List<ClassA>();
    classAList.Add(new ClassB());
    classAList.Add(new ClassC());
}
```

Now if I want to do this:

```
ClassB retrievedClass = List[0];
```

So that I can execute a method on the sublass of ClassA, the compiler forces me to downcast to a specific sublass type:

```
ClassB retrievedClass = (ClassB) List[0];
```

**So my question are as follows:**

1. Why won't the framework do an implicit cast for me, since the types are compatible?
2. Isn't this operation a type of unboxing since you need to cast to a specific type?
3. What is the cost of the downcast as compared to a downcast from **Object**?
4. Is there a better/more efficient way to store/access subclasses that share the same   superclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1. Why won't the framework do an implicit cast for me, since the types are compatible?`

Well, the types *aren't* compatible. Not every `ClassA` is a `ClassB`, and so you need to explicitly specify that you want to downcast to `ClassB` when you retrieve a `ClassA` from the list.

`2. Isn't this operation a type of unboxing since you need to cast to a specific type?`

Well, no. You're not doing any unboxing here, since you're never retrieving any elements from `classAList`. Also, boxing is the act of making a value type (a primitive such as `int`, `char`, etc.) into a reference type, which is not going on here, so you're doubly not unboxing here.

`3. What is the cost of the downcast as compared to a downcast from an Object?`

They probably have exactly the same cost, as `ClassB` and `ClassC` are both child classes of both `ClassA` and `object`.

`4. Is there a better/more efficient way to store/access subclasses that share the same superclass?`

No. If you want to store a list of `ClassA` or anything that extends it, then what you are doing right now is exactly what you need to do.

Comment: This mostly makes sense, although are you sure about **Boxing is used when using primitives in generics**?  I was pretty sure that the whole point of generics is to avoid boxing and unboxing altogether since the objects are stored as their native type, regardless of whether they are a reference or value type?

Comment: @Leon Ah, yes. You're right. I modified my answer. (All I had to do was remove that sentence.)